# Delete trigger mysql on another table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am new on mysql and I am try to create a before delete trigger on mysql.

I have a table call "persons" and I need delete a record on another table called "ldap_entries"

the table "persons" have a ID, unique and this id it is on "ldap_entries" but the columns it is called "keyval".

so I am try to do like this: but not working

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete`
BEFORE DELETE ON `persons`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM ldap_entries WHERE ldap_entries.keyval = OLD.id 
END $$
```

Here is my describe output:

```
mysql> describe persons;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| surname    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| package    | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| macaddress | varchar(21)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| customer   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| address    | varchar(140) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| phone      | varchar(9)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| email      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created    | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| updated    | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe ldap_entries
    -> ;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| dn        | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| oc_map_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| parent    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| keyval    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also in response to the comments:

- I don't know if InnoDB is being used.
- There isn't a FK relationship between the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the delimter to `$$` and then back to `;`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete`
BEFORE DELETE ON `persons`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM ldap_entries WHERE ldap_entries.keyval = OLD.id 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```